# how to properly loop through form elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

What I'm trying to do is to get the value from each form element with type 'text'. Can you  teach me the proper way of getting the  values from the textbox and outputting those values using javascript?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function trap(){
for(var i=0; i<document.x.elements.length; i++)
{
document.write(document.x.elements[i].value + "<br />");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form name="x">

<?php
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
?>

qty #<?php echo $i; ?>
<input type="text" name="qty[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value=""/>
<img src="add-icon.png" onmouseover="trap();">

<?php } ?>

</form>

</body>
```

I checked if its getting the correct number of form elements of type text:

```
document.write(document.x.elements.length);
```

And its the same to the number I specified in the php for loop.However I'm only getting the value of element #1. It doesn't seem to be fetching the value from `qty[1]`

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is another:

You use `document.write()`  inside your function. This method you cannot use after the page is loaded, because it will overwrite the whole document-> also the function itself. By that after first call  of write the function doesn't exist anymore, you got a new document which only contains the data you've just written.

Use instead of write() other methods, for example this should work:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.x.elements[i].value ));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
```